# Story about an adaptive, intelligent parasite "defeated" by humans

Tags: story-identification

Several years ago I read the plot synopsis on Wikipedia (bad form, I know) for a sci-fi story with an intelligent parasite that infected humans. The parasite adapted to all attempts to defeat or drive it out (e.g., by growing a hard exoskeleton on the affected person). The plot twist was that the parasite was conscious, and I believe the end of the book involved a woman "saving" her husband from the parasite by telling it that she would find it a new host if it would spare her husband.

Sorry for the kind of incoherent summary, it's been a long time since I read it.

For years I labored under the assumption that this story was Jeff Vandermeer's [*Annihilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation_(VanderMeer_novel)), but I recently read *Annihilation* and it definitely isn't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Your title says the parasite was defeated by humans, but you put that in scare quotes and in the body of your question says it was able to adapt to any attempt to defeat it.  Can you clarify why you phrased the title that way?  Was there just one parasite or did it reproduce and infect multiple people?

Comment: I think it reproduced in the original story? I was referring to the fact that the wife managed to save her husband, but that the larger implication was that they hadn't defeated it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any chance that it's [Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(novel)), by Michael Crichton? It's not a perfect match, but there are some similarities:

- The novel is about self-replicating nanobots that start as mindless swarms but evolve to take over human hosts.
- By the end of the novel, they are shown to have a form of intelligence.
- It is revealed that the protagonist's wife had been infected for some time.
- In the climactic scene, the wife is briefly freed from the parasite and tells her husband to escape and save their children while she uses the opportunity to destroy the facility they're in.

Comment: No, I don't think this was it :( I distinctly remember the parasite responding to a person (verbally) offering a truce.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *The Puppet Masters* by Robert A. Heinlein?  Since you remember it from a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters) rather than the book itself, I'll quote the first paragraph of the plot section:

> In the summer of 2007, Earth is under clandestine attack. Slug-like creatures, arriving in flying saucers, are attaching themselves to people's backs, taking control of their victims' nervous systems, and manipulating those people as puppets. The Old Man, the head of a clandestine national security agency called the Section, goes to Des Moines, Iowa, with Sam and Mary, two of his best agents, to investigate a flying saucer report, but much more seriously the ominous disappearance of the six agents sent previously. They discover that "the slugs" are steadily taking over Des Moines, but they cannot convince the US president to declare an emergency.

Comment: Unlikely, since it's possible to kill the parasites by crushing them in a bare hand; they definitely _not_ grow armour.

Comment: I believe they evolve a shell later in the book when they get tired of being squished.

Comment: If you want to direct people to a non-copyright-violating (probably) and likely safer site, you should try the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/puppetmasterswal0000hein) instead.  (Or you could try the original serialization in [Galaxy](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v02n06_1951-09), [part 2](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n01_1951-10), [part 3](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n02_1951-11).)

Comment: No, this doesn't sound right :( it definitely wasn't Heinlein. and iirc the parasite wasn't an alien.